# Find value in ranges in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a data structure that looks like this and it represents the different quarters for a company:

```
var quarters = [
 { beginning: 11, end: 1 },
 { beginning: 2, end: 4 },
 { beginning: 5, end: 7 },
 { beginning: 8, end: 10 }
]
```

Now, given a number, let's call it `month`. I need to get which object in that array has the month. For example, if `month` is 12, it should give me the first object `{ beginning: 11, end: 1 }`

I have made this function:

```
function findQuarter(month) {
 return quarters.find(
    q => q.beginning <= month && q.end >= month + 1,
  );
}
```

But for example, if the month is 11, it won't find any quarter, and it should find the first one. It doesn't know that the `end` doesn't necessarily need to be bigger.

That quarters variable, is customizable, so it can be different, for example:

```
 var quarters = [
     { beginning: 1, end: 3 },
     { beginning: 4, end: 6 },
     { beginning: 7, end: 9 },
     { beginning: 10, end: 12 }
    ]
```

or

```
 var quarters = [
             { beginning: 12, end: 2 },
             { beginning: 3, end: 5 },
             { beginning: 6, end: 8 },
             { beginning: 9, end: 11 }
            ]
```

Which if the month given is `1` should find `{ beginning: 12, end: 2 }` but it wouldn't.

Which represents the most common quarter type in companies.

Comment: Add a `if (end < beginning) end = end + 12;` ?

Comment: That would not solve the case if the first quarter started on `12 and ended on 2` and the given month was 1, because the beginning would be bigger than the given month, so the first condition wouldn't satisfy.

Comment: Ok, then add a `if (month > end) month = month + 12` as well :)

Comment: If I do that, then it won't work for the case where one of the quarters is `beginning: 1, end: 3` and the given month is 2.

Comment: Had a typo, see edit :D (after the first if)

Comment: Ok, let me try. Why don't you add an answer? Happy to accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could take the remainder with 12 and adjust the value to a fixed interval between zero and the maximum slot length.

This approach moves the values of the beginning to zero with the pattern

```
(value + 12 - beginning) % 12
         ^^                   keep the result positive
              ^^^^^^^^^       take zero instead of a beginning
                         ^^^^ prevent number greater than 12
```

and the end with the adjustment for the check of smaller or equal. The remainder operator keeps the value in wa wanted range an by using zero base value, all values are smaller than twelve as well.

```js
function findMonth(month) {
    return quarters.find(({ beginning, end }) =>
        (month + 12 - beginning) % 12 <= (end + 12 - beginning) % 12 
    );
}

var quarters = [
    { beginning: 8, end: 10 }, 
    { beginning: 11, end: 1 }, 
    { beginning: 2, end: 4 }, 
    { beginning: 5, end: 7 }
];

console.log(findMonth(1));
console.log(findMonth(2));
console.log(findMonth(3));
console.log(findMonth(4));
console.log(findMonth(5));
console.log(findMonth(6));
console.log(findMonth(7));
console.log(findMonth(8));
console.log(findMonth(9));
console.log(findMonth(10));
console.log(findMonth(11));
console.log(findMonth(12));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This is awesome!

Comment: yea, Nina is very skilled +1

Comment: This works great but is hard for me to understand what are we doing. Could you explain a little bit?

Answer (score 1):

Your condition was not complete and I also use `filter()` method to achieve such things:

```js
function findQuarter(month) {
 return quarters.filter(
    q => {
      if (q.beginning <= month && q.end >= month) {
        return q
      } else {
        if (q.beginning > q.end && month > q.end && month > q.beginning) return q
      }
    }
  );
}

var quarters = [
   { beginning: 1, end: 3 },
   { beginning: 11, end: 1 },
   { beginning: 4, end: 6 },
   { beginning: 7, end: 9 },
   { beginning: 10, end: 12 }
]

console.log(findQuarter(1))
console.log(findQuarter(12))
console.log(findQuarter(9))
```

Comment: This solution fails. Try findQuarter(9), you get two results.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this.

```js
var quarters = [{
    beginning: 11,
    end: 1
  },
  {
    beginning: 2,
    end: 4
  },
  {
    beginning: 5,
    end: 7
  },
  {
    beginning: 8,
    end: 10
  }
];

function findQuarter(month) {
  // Sort your quarters
  quarters = quarters.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.beginning < b.beginning;
  });

  return quarters.find(function(q) {
    if (q.beginning <= q.end)
      return q.beginning <= month && month <= q.end;
    if (q.beginning > q.end)
      return q.beginning <= month && month <= 12 ||
        1 <= month && month <= q.end;
  });
}

for (var i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
  console.log("For month " + i + " quarter: " + JSON.stringify(findQuarter(i)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What @Benjamin Gruenbaum said.  Update your function like this:

```
function findQuarter(month) {
 return quarters.find(
    let effectiveEnd = (q.end < q.beginning) ? q.end + 12 : q.end
    q => q.beginning <= month && effectiveEnd >= month + 1,
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you the following solutions:

```
    // QUARTERS SOURCE
    var quarters = [
      { beginning: 11, end: 1 },
      { beginning: 2, end: 4 },
      { beginning: 5, end: 7 },
      { beginning: 8, end: 10 }
    ];

    // FUNCTION
    const findQuarter = (month) => quarters.find(q => q.beginning <= month && q.end < q.beginning ? q.end + 12 : q.end >= month)

    // TO TEST
    for(var i = 1; i < 12; i++) {
      console.log(`The month ${i} is in the quarter ${findQuarter(i).beginning} - ${findQuarter(i).end}`);
    }
```

The result is the following:

```
    The month 1 is in the quarter 11 - 1
    The month 2 is in the quarter 2 - 4
    The month 3 is in the quarter 2 - 4
    The month 4 is in the quarter 2 - 4
    The month 5 is in the quarter 5 - 7
    The month 6 is in the quarter 5 - 7
    The month 7 is in the quarter 5 - 7
    The month 8 is in the quarter 8 - 10
    The month 9 is in the quarter 8 - 10
    The month 10 is in the quarter 8 - 10
    The month 11 is in the quarter 11 - 1
```

Is that all you need? :)